# How to determine the LineHeight of a TextBox in pixels in WinRT

Tags: c#, xaml, textbox, windows-runtime

How do I determine the height of the lines of a TextBox in pixels in WinRT?

With Windows Phone, I could get (or set) this value through `TextBox.LineHeight`, but this doesn't seem to be available to WinRT.

I can't work out how to do this, but I need to get the value so that I can set my padding and margins correctly in my layout. I'm trying to set the upper and lower padding to ((`TextBox.Height` - `TextBox.LineHeight`) / 2). Can anyone offer any suggestions?

Comment: From the sounds of it, there may be a better way all together to do what you're trying to do that wouldn't/shouldn't involve actively looking at lineheights to set margins/padding elsewhere.

Comment: Could you provide an example? I'm trying to keep the active line in the middle of the screen through a combination of setting the padding and using `ChangeView` on the `ScrollViewer` of the `TextBox` to center the active line.